# Removing urls from bibliography, without editing .bst file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, ieeetran

First of all, I have tried [Disabling URLs in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26318/disabling-urls-in-bibliography?rq=1) and it does not work.

Secondly, I am not repeating [Suppress certain URLS in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166673/suppress-certain-urls-in-bibliography) as I prefer to not edit the bib file, which is automatically generated.

I am preparing a conference publication to be submitted to IEEE; so, please don't suggest editing the bibliography style file (IEEEtran.bst).

I have a .bib file generated from Mendeley which contains `url` fields. Currently, I manually delete them. However, in favor of efficiency, I would like either

1. A way to export from Mendeley without urls

or

2. A way to disable insertion of url in the bibliography, preferrably via a directive or a flag

preferably both!

---

A minimal example [source.tex]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{MyBSTcontrol}
\title{I need a vacation!}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{tokyo coder}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Institute of Random Stuff, A big University, Japan}}
\maketitle
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
kill me now \cite{Levecque2017} \\does happiness exist?

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{science,disabl_url}

% that's all folks
\end{document}
```

The bib file is [science.bib]

```
@article{Levecque2017,
author = {Levecque, Katia and Anseel, Frederik and {De Beuckelaer}, Alain and {Van der Heyden}, Johan and Gisle, Lydia},
doi = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.respol.2017.02.008},
isbn = {3907},
issn = {0048-7333},
journal = {Research Policy},
keywords = {GHQ-12,Mental health,PhD students,Psychosocial working conditions,Work organization},
number = {4},
pages = {868--879},
publisher = {Elsevier B.V.},
title = {{Work organization and mental health problems in PhD students}},
url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0048733317300422},
volume = {46},
year = {2017}
}
```

Second bib file is [disabl_url.bib]

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{MyBSTcontrol,
    CTLuse_url = "no",
}
```

Comment: I have no idea if Mendeley can suppress the url export. Regarding the tex side: Make a complete example so that one can test how the bbl looks like.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress certain URLS in bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166673/suppress-certain-urls-in-bibliography)

Comment: I *think* my old question (not even the answers to it) answers your question.  Without an example we can't tell how you're using the bibliography so I can't be sure.

Comment: Well at least your second point looks like a duplicate of the question you linked to.

Comment: Otherwise on a unix-like (or windows with cygwin) system, from the commandline: `sed 's/^\s*url.*,//' bibliography.bib >temp.bib` will delete lines starting "url" (it will leave a blank line but that doesn't matter).

Comment: Can you please show a minimal example? One single bib entry with a URL suffices, together with a minimal document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChrisH: This is not a duplicate to your question. Your question uses biblatex, but here a bst-file is used.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, good spot, thanks.  I'd looked for a bibtex tag or just a mention of bibtex, but missed the file extension.  I'll promote my other comment to an answer as well, if the question is likely to stay open.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268987/36296

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling URLs in bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26318/disabling-urls-in-bibliography)

Comment: Why can't you use [this solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268987/110998)?

Comment: @gernot tried that; does not work

Comment: @samcarter tried that; does not work

Comment: @samcarter Please read the question before commenting that it is a duplicate of Disabling URLs in bibliography. It is not.

Comment: @tokyoCoder We read the little information that you have provided, and  for this, [Disabling URLs in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268987/110998) is the perfect answer. May it be that *you* didn't read the answer? The answer requires you to modify the **bib** file by setting a flag (something that you are looking for), **not** the **bst** file. If you really tried that and failed: Explain what you did and what you mean by "it doesn't work". And provide more information, like an MWE including a small bib file.

Comment: @tokyoCoder Please excuse, but I did read your question. You are asking, quote "preferrably via a directive or a flag" and the linked answer is exactly that. If it does not work for you, please show us the code you tried, the linked answer clearly works - just saying "does not work" is not really helpful information.

Comment: @samcarter I spend several hours trying different solutions including https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268987/110998 . I just failed to see how it solves the problem, just like how you did not see why it doesn't. I finally managed to reduce my file to a minimal example. I hope that could clear things a little better. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @gernot. Thank you for trying to help me. If you had explicitly asked for a working example, it would have been clear to me what I should have done. Just marking it as duplicate did not solve my issue, rather left me wondering how it solves it in the first place. In any case, I am updating the question with an example. I hope that clears things a little.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for the help. I have added an example. Maybe it can clear the situation a little more.

Comment: Your entry in disable_url.bib works fine for and disables the url's. So what is your problem?

Comment: @tokyoCoder Using your MWE I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMGry.png -> no urls. What does your output look like?

Comment: Which version of `IEEEtran.bst` do you use? The current one seems to be `Version 1.14 (2015/08/26)`, and it has the handling of `CTLuse_url` built in.

Comment: @gernot I was using the `IEEEtran.bst` from IEEE's conference web page http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html . It is `Version 1.12`
Using `Version 1.14` from CTAN solved the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it caused by an outdated package version.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I also request you to update the answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26318/disabling-urls-in-bibliography because otherwise, people will never find the solution particularly considering that IEEE website itself is providing outdated packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a recent copy of `IEEEtran.bst` from CTAN, at least `Version 1.14 (2015/08/26)`. Then proceed as described in [Disabling URLs in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268987/110998).

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to automatically edit the .bib file to remove the url field.  After exporting your file from mendeley, you would need to delete all lines starting `url` (with possible whitespace first), writing to a new .bib file (as your master bibliography is in mendeley you *could* overwrite the original but in the general case I don't suggest you do).  This is easily done on the commandline using `sed` (available on all unix-like systems, including mac, also possible on windows by using Cygwin or MinGW, or just [installing it](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)).  Any decent programmer's text editor will also provide a way to do the same thing (regex find/replace).

The command you actually need is `sed 's/^\s*url.*,//' bibliography.bib >temp.bib`, which breaks down to run `sed` to substitute (`s/`) from the beginning of the line (`^`) one or more (`*`) whitespace characters (`\s`) followed by "url", and one or more (`*`) of any character except newline (`.`) up to a comma.  The replacement is blank (given by the `//` as `/` is the delimiter).  This leaves a blank line where the url was, but bibtex won't mind.

If the url is the last item in the entry, with no comma at the end of the line, this won't work.  So if mendeley (I tried it once and never used it again) puts the url last in the entry, we'll need a slightly different replacement, which will depend on whether the final closing `}` of the entry is on its own line or on the same line as the url.  A more complex regex could take these variables into account, but I find it that it's better to keep things simple as there's less to go wrong.